Is there any way to use valgrind from C/C++ via the API?
I want to write tool, that collects different runtime information about executable including heap information. Valgrind is perfect tool to get such info. The key information, that I want to obtain is total heap usage: X allocs, X frees, X bytes allocated. However I haven't found another way to use it except to use popen to execute "valgrind --trace-children ./executable" and parse output from stdout. Ideally, I want to have something like this:
#include "valgrind.h"

int main() {
    valgrind::valgrind_results res = valgrind::valgrind_memcheck(
        "path/to/executable", 
        std::vector<std::string>{"--trace-children", "--other-options"}
    );
    std::cout << res.allocs << res.frees << res.bytes_allocated << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Does something like this exist?

Perhaps use popen and read the output with fgets etc.?

@Someprogrammerdude actually, that's what I'm doing, I just decided not to complicate the issue with such details.

So, you are looking for a library that provides Valgrind functionality?

@UlrichEckhardt Yeah. Or maybe valgrind itself provides some API for this, but I haven't found it.

Back when I used the Manx C compiler (1980s), their heap management had (non-standard) functions to query the heap status.  Those functions could provide allocs, frees, current bytes allocated, highwater bytes allocated, and other internal details.  Have you considered using a heap manager that has the functionality you want?

@Eljay No, I didn't consider other heap managers except valgrind yet. Do you have any examples?

For example, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=storage-alternative-vendor-heap-manager

Valgrind is perfect if you don't mind the slowdown, which can be as much as 50x in some cases (but then you shouldn't have been using C or C++ in the furst place). If you want your program to run fast, then every major heap management library (including glibc) lets you query various statistics. Type man mallinfo in your shell.

Take a look at heaptrack https://github.com/KDE/heaptrack

Consider --xml option (which will make parsing easier, although perhaps less advantageous for C++) and the --xml-socket or --log-socket options, which delivers the data more conveniently.
